# Not able to post to facebook wall using facebook4j java

Tags: java, facebook, facebook4j

I am trying to post a message to facebook using facebook 4j library. Can someone help what is wrong in the below code?

```
public class status{

static String appID         = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
static String appSecretKey  = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
static String tok           = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";


public static void update_FB_Status(String appID, String appSecretKey) {
    Facebook fb = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
    fb.setOAuthAppId(appID, appSecretKey);
    /*fb.setOAuthAccessToken(arg0);*/
    fb.setOAuthAccessToken(new facebook4j.auth.AccessToken(tok, null));
    try {
        fb.postStatusMessage("hello everyone");
    } catch (FacebookException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    status.update_FB_Status(appID, appSecretKey);
}
```

I am getting the below error message:

```
FacebookException{statusCode=403, errorType='OAuthException', errorMessage='(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
      either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both manage_pages \
      and publish_pages permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
      requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with \
      sufficient administrative permission', errorCode=200, errorSubcode=-1, version=2.4.6}
at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:179)
at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
at facebook4j.FacebookImpl.post(FacebookImpl.java:2887)
at facebook4j.FacebookImpl._postStatusMessage(FacebookImpl.java:2792)
at facebook4j.FacebookImpl.postStatusMessage(FacebookImpl.java:853)
at facebook4j.FacebookImpl.postStatusMessage(FacebookImpl.java:849)
```

Comment: please add any error/debug information, right now we only know that "it does not work". we need more information, i´m afraid. we can only guess that you are trying to post to a USER profile, which is not possible anymore.

Comment: @luschn: I have updated the error message

Comment: so what´s unclear about the error message? what token are you using? where do you want to post? what permissions does your token have?

Comment: I am using user access token, and I have nearly all permissions. I want to post it in my facebook wall

Comment: But my manager is showing a demo of 1 application which posts to facebook wall using userid and password. He wants me to do the same for my java application as well.

Comment: You are not allowed to ask or use a Facebook users password.

Comment: what wizkid said. there is no way to do what you want to achieve in any allowed way. also, don´t just try stuff with "nearly all permissions", the docs tell you exactly what permissions you need for specific api calls.